# Converts a Fahrenheit degree to Celsius in java

Tags: java

I am trying converts a Fahrenheit degree to Celsius.Now I have a Error,When I use this:

```
double fahrenheit=input.nextDouble();

double celsius= ( **5** /9)*(fahrenheit-32);(Error)
```

Then again I am trying given **(5.0)** then it is work why?

Comment: 5 / 9 is integer division: it operates quotient (which is 0 in your case) and remainder (which is 5)

Comment: i can not understand clearly please can explain this

Comment: What don't you understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The values '5' and '9' are integers and 5/9 is considered as `0` instead of `0.55` which is why you get the wrong answer. When two integers are divided, the answer is `floor()` automatically. It is necessary to write either one of '5' and '9' as 5.0 and 9.0

A better practice is to always write both as `5.0` and `9.0` or write them as `double(5)` and `double(9)`
Since multiplication and other operations are mostly left recursive, this statement would work fine as well.
`(fahrenheit-32)*5/9;` as the statement starts with a double value

Answer (score 3):

when you are dividing `5/9` then you will get `integer` output because both `5` and `9` are `integers`.But you are dividing `5.0/9` then you are diving double value by `integer` so the output is double

You can also do `(double)5/9`

Comment: @Rehena you are welcome.If you find any problems in java then you can drop me a mail and I will try to help you

Answer (score 2):

> Then again I am trying given (5.0) then it is work why?

`5 / 9` divides *integers* (whole numbers) and gives you the result `0`. `5.0 / 9` divides *doubles* (numbers that can have a fractional portion), so you get the correct result, `0.5555555555555556`.